# Wordpress add posts to sub menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to make a list of all custom posts show as a sub-menu on the theme's main menu. I need them to be added dynamically, as soon as I add a new post of that type, and not through a custom menu.
Basically I would like to have this:

```
Menu
- custom post 1
- custom post 2
- ...etc
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Could be done by a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-auto-menu/

Answer (score -1):

**Try This:**

I just added filter called "`wp_nav_menu_items`"
please add the following:

**1.**
**change** your menu name in if condition

**2.** change your post type in array "cp_args"

**3.** Please add class in menu and submenu class

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_todaysdate_in_menu', 10, 2);
    function add_todaysdate_in_menu( $items, $args ) {
        if( $args->menu == 'Menu_name')  { //change your menu name
            $items .= '<li><a class="quick_enq" href="#">CUSTOM POST</a>';
            $items .= '<ul>';
            $cp_args = array('post_type'=>'YOUR_POST_TYPE','posts_per_page'=>-1);
            $get_cp_query = new WP_Query($cp_args);
            while($get_cp_query->have_posts()):$get_cp_query->the_post();

                    $items .= '<li><a class="sub_class" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
            endwhile;
                    $items .= '</ul></li>';
        }
        return $items;
    }
```